# When to really use a branch in git?

Tags: git

I have automated a few test cases and pushed them for review. However I need to continue developing other testcases in the same code. I cannot create a new sandbox everytime as my changes are not really in the stream and hence I dont get them in my newly created local. Is branching really the way to work? If so how do I keep my currently working changes private and isolated so that nobody is aware of it.. Not even the master?

Comment: What do you mean by "sandbox"? And what do mean by "the master"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely. Is it how to I keep my local working copy private? It is already. If the question is how to keep changes private when moving to other work, then maybe try [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Answer (score 3):

Saying you have pushed cases for review indicates you are working in an organisation that uses git to do code review. So presumably they have a plan for how to do this, whether written down or just 'common knowledge'.

So you should follow what the organisation does. Git is just a toolbox with a variety of tools in in, one of which is called 'branch'. So there is no generic answer to your question based on solely knowing the fact you use git.

Any more than there is a valid answer to the question 'I have a hammer, what should I hit?'

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question you have created a branch (lets call it **A**) and submitted it for review before it can be merged into **master**. And you now need to do more work that builds on top of work in branch **A**. This work will be done in a new branch that we'll call **B**.

Obviously, if you create a new branch off of **master** you wont have the new features you've introduced in **A**. So, you have two options.

One. Branch **B** off of **A** rather than **master**.
Two. Branch **B** off of **master** and then do a merge from **A**.

In either case, you include all work from **A** in branch **B**. **B**, of course, can't be merged until **A** has been merged without effectively also merging in **A**.

The risk factor here is that if your work in **A** gets rejected, your work on **B** may need to be extensively rewritten, but that is a risk you cannot avoid without waiting for the review of **A** to be complete.

Eventually **A** gets merged into **master** and the problem goes away. If branch **A** gets revised during the review process you will, of course, have to merge those changes into **B**.

Comment: The last sentence is not really true since A will have been merged to master at that point and git will just handle that without issues provided there are no conflicts.